# How to hide JSON data by creating a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In order to hide the JSON data (so that it can be faded in later), I modified the `a1.start` function by creating div called "loading," but in the Javascript Console in Chrome, there is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

in the HTML:  `a1.start($("#cakeHook"),"a1data.json");`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <title>Cake Baby Bakery</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="a1.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/basica1.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="cakeHook" ></div>
        <script>

        a1.start($("#cakeHook"),"a1data.json");

        </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

**a1.start**

```
a1.start = function(hookElementSelection, dataurlForJsonFile) {

jQuery('<div/>', {
id: 'loading',
text: 'Loading...'
}).appendTo('hookElementSelection');

$('hookElementSelection).hide();

    a1.products = {};
    a1.recipes = {};
    a1.suppliers = {};
    a1.bakedRecipes = [];

    //make an ajax call and wait for success
    $.ajax({url:dataurlForJsonFile}).success(function(data) {

        //get the recipe data
        parseJSONData(data);

        //put the recipes on the page
        $.each(a1.recipes, function(i, recipe) {
            recipe.render(hookElementSelection);
        });
        renderCalculator(hookElementSelection); //add in the final calculation logic
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to use the variable, you are using a string instead:

```
.appendTo('hookElementSelection')
```

should be:

```
.appendTo(hookElementSelection)
```

Then you have an unterminated string when you try to use the variable again:

```
$('hookElementSelection).hide();
```

should be:

```
hookElementSelection.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighting right here on SO indicates your error. You're missing a `'` character:

```
$('hookElementSelection').hide();
```

However, it looks like you're already passing a reference to the jQuery object in the first argument to the function, so the replacing that line of code with the following should be sufficient:

```
hookElementSelection.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in lines 6 and 8 there is an error in your a1start.js. Change to:

```
}).appendTo(hookElementSelection);

hookElementSelection.hide();
```

Remove the single quotes, as `hookElementSelection` is a variable being an jQuery object and it can't be used as a string.